# Grouping array elements

Tags: matlab

I have the following MATLAB code

```
out = cell(max(A), 1);
for i = 1:numel(out)
    out{i} = find(A == i);
end
```

in which `A` contains all entries in `1:max(A)`, with a different order and possible repetitions. At the end of the code fragment `out{i}` contains the indices where `i` appears in `A`. The question is - is it possible to "vectorize" the above, instead of doing a loop? I believe it can be done with `accumarray` but I cannot see exactly how.

Comment: I would assume the third output of [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) gives you what you're looking for.

Comment: The third output of unique does not group the indices of equal entries into a cell array.

Comment: Why do you need them grouped into a cell array?

Comment: Because it is the input to a 3rd party function which I did not write and do not intend to change.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I came up with the answer

```
out = accumarray(A, 1:max(A), [], @(x) {x})
```